# Unable to install Ruby 3.2.0 with Rbenv -- Missing Pysch gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I'm currently trying to install Ruby 3.2.0 with Rbenv and I'm getting this error every time.

```
BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 22.04 using ruby-build 20230202)
Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20230202161804.1244.1gO1Ch

Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20230202161804.1244.log 
Last 10 log lines:
Fix the problems, then remove these directories and try again if you want.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20230202161804.1244.1gO1Ch/ruby-3.2.0'
Generating RDoc documentation
/tmp/ruby-build.20230202161804.1244.1gO1Ch/ruby-3.2.0/lib/yaml.rb:3: warning: It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby. uh-oh! RDoc had a problem:
cannot load such file -- psych

run with --debug for full backtrace
make: *** [uncommon.mk:598: rdoc] Error 1
```

It seems this gem PSYCH is missing, but when I run

`gem install psych`

I get this other message.

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing psych:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/psych-5.0.2/ext/psych
/root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/bin/ruby -I /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/3.1.0 extconf.rb
checking for yaml.h... no
yaml.h not found
extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-libyaml-source-dir
        --without-libyaml-source-dir
        --with-yaml-0.1-dir
        --without-yaml-0.1-dir
        --with-yaml-0.1-include
        --without-yaml-0.1-include=${yaml-0.1-dir}/include
        --with-yaml-0.1-lib
        --without-yaml-0.1-lib=${yaml-0.1-dir}/lib
        --with-yaml-0.1-config
        --without-yaml-0.1-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-libyaml-dir
        --with-libyaml-include
        --without-libyaml-include=${libyaml-dir}/include
        --with-libyaml-lib
        --without-libyaml-lib=${libyaml-dir}/lib
 
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:
 
  /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.1.0/psych-5.0.2/mkmf.log
 
extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/psych-5.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.1.0/psych-5.0.2/gem_make.out
```

Any help is super appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Following this discussion: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/discussions/2118, have you tried installing `libyaml` and `libyaml-dev` first? `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install libyaml libyaml-dev`

Comment: To elaborate on the above comment, some gems contain native extensions written in C that must be compiled. They often require libraries to be installed on the host, in this case the source for libyaml so that psych can access them and complete the compilation. Although it isn't very intuitive, if a gem fails to compile its native extensions you should look at the logs to see what it's looking for. (in this case, libyaml is all over those logs)

Comment: Only `libyaml-dev` is needed

Answer (score 12):

I encountered a similar error while installing Ruby 3.2.2 with Rbenv on Ubuntu 22.04:

```
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20230515033830.1482.MJkBPP/ruby-3.2.2'
Generating RDoc documentation
/tmp/ruby-build.20230515033830.1482.MJkBPP/ruby-3.2.2/lib/yaml.rb:3: warning: It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
uh-oh! RDoc had a problem:
cannot load such file -- psych

run with --debug for full backtrace
make: *** [uncommon.mk:598: rdoc] Error 1
```

In my case, by installing `libyaml-dev` and then reinstalling Ruby 3.2.2, I was able to resolve the error:

```
sudo apt-get install libyaml-dev
rbenv install 3.2.2
```

Comment: On OpenSUSE the command was `sudo zypper in libyaml-devel`

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Mac, first install libyaml with brew and then retry installing Ruby.